# Error opening crystal report in excel format

Tags: crystal-reports

We have an application written in VB.NET 2003 which has built in Crystal reports. When we install the application on Windows 2008 server
we get the following error while trying to open crystal report in excel format 
Error is : Error in File :"....rpt" Error detected by export DLL. 
The report opens up fine in PDF on server

Opeing report in Excel works fine on my local(development) machine...But this error is thrown on server...

Kindly help me resolve this issue and how to fix it?..

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the patch crnet11win from businessobjects.com

Comment: Thanks, i downloaded the patch.I recompiled my application and put it on server but same error.
 Could you please explain in details what steps to be taken to resolve the problem at server side.